# Computation time for RSA?

Tags: python, performance, rsa

I'm quite new to programming and had done a Cryptography course on Coursera before I stared learning Python. Recently, as a project, I wanted to write my own code for the RSA algorithm. I have just finished writing the encryption process which is as such:

[image]

However, the program is running now and is taking a long time. I did notice, it took a long time for the keys and modulos to compute because of the sheer size. Because I am new to all of this, I don't know enough and was wondering if there was any way to speed up the process?

If my code is required to be posted, I can do it however I would prefer a more general answer on how to speed up code.

Thanks

Comment: yes, the code is required for us to help you.

Comment: Are you using the three-argument form of Python's built-in `pow` function?  If not, you might want to look at that.  (`help(pow)`)

Comment: SO is not an appropriate place to ask for a "general answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too took the course on coursera. You should check the following libraries out, it can speed up your calculations tremendously :

```
1.) http://userpages.umbc.edu/~rcampbel/Computers/Python/lib/numbthy.py ( check the powmod function)
2.) gmpy2 (gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mpz.html)
3.) mpmath (code.google.com/p/mpmath/)
```